# Exponential Backoff not returning data in promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure if I am approaching this the correct way. I have tried a few different versions of the implementation but am putting the one here that works when the backoff path is NOT used.

So, I have an `index.js` that is just:

```
import { Lizard } from './lizard.js';
const lizard = new Lizard();

const global_data = await lizard.global();
console.log(global_data);
```

In my `lizard.js` I have a class with functions but for the sake of saving space and noise I will only place the ones that matter here:

```
export class Lizard {
  global() {
    const path = '/global';
    return this._request(path);
  };

  _buildRequestOptions(path, params) {
    if (isObject(params)) params = querystring.stringify(params);
    else params = undefined;

    if (params == undefined) path = `/api/v${API_VERSION}${path}`;
    else path = `/api/v${API_VERSION}${path}?${params}`;

    // Return options
    return {
      path,
      method: 'GET',
      host: HOST,
      port: 443,
      timeout: Lizard.TIMEOUT,
    };
  };

  async _request(path, params) {
    const options = this._buildRequestOptions(path, params);
    const maxRetries = 10;

    function waitFor(milliseconds) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
    }

    async function request(options, retries) {
      if (retries > 0) {
        const timeToWait = 15000 * retries;
        console.log(`waiting for ${timeToWait}ms...`);
        await waitFor(timeToWait);
      }

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
          let body = [];

          res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body.push(chunk);
          });

          res.on('end', () => {
            try {
              body = Buffer.concat(body);
              body = body.toString();

              if (body.startsWith('<!DOCTYPE html>')) {
                _WARN_('Invalid request', 'There was a problem with your request. The parameter(s) you gave are missing or incorrect.');
              } else if (body.startsWith('Throttled')) {
                _WARN_('Throttled request', 'There was a problem with request limit.');
              }

              body = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (error) {
              reject(error);
            };

            const returnObject = ReturnObject(
              !(res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300),
              res.statusMessage,
              res.statusCode,
              body
            )

            if (returnObject.code != 429) {
              resolve(returnObject);
            } else {
              if (retries < maxRetries) {
                console.log('retrying...');
                return request(options, retries + 1);
              } else {
                console.log("Max retries reached. Bubbling the error up");
                resolve(returnObject);
              }
            }
          });
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => reject(error));

        req.on('timeout', () => {
          req.abort();
          reject(new Error(`Lizard API request timed out. Current timeout is: ${Lizard.TIMEOUT} milliseconds`));
        });

        // End request
        req.end();
      });
    }

    return await request(options, 0);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do this in a very difficult way. For anyone else that may stumble upon this here was my ultimate solution:

`lizard.js`:

```
async function request(path, params, retries = 0, maxRetries = 10) {
  let options = await buildRequestOptions(path, params);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      let body = [];

      // Set body on data
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      });

      // On end, end the Promise
      res.on('end', async () => {
        try {
          body = Buffer.concat(body);
          body = body.toString();

          // Check if page is returned instead of JSON
          if (body.startsWith('<!DOCTYPE html>')) {
            _WARN_('Invalid request', 'There was a problem with your request. The parameter(s) you gave are missing or incorrect.');
          } else if (body.startsWith('Throttled')) {
            _WARN_('Throttled request', 'There was a problem with request limit.');
          }

          // Attempt to parse
          body = JSON.parse(body);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        };

        if (res.statusCode == 429 && retries < maxRetries) {
          const timeToWait = 60000 + (1000 * retries);
          console.error('Throttled request ' + retries + ' time(s)');
          console.log(`Retrying in ${timeToWait}ms...`);

          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(request(path, params, retries + 1));
          }, timeToWait);
        } else {
          resolve(
            objectify(
              !(res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300),
              res.statusMessage,
              res.statusCode,
              body
            )
          );
        }
      });
    });

    // On error, reject the Promise
    req.on('error', (error) => reject(error));

    // On timeout, reject the Promise
    req.on('timeout', () => {
      req.abort();
      reject(new Error(`Lizard API request timed out. Current timeout is: ${TIMEOUT} milliseconds`));
    });

    // End request
    req.end();
  });
};
```

I still resolve the object on fail as `429` is too many requests, so anything else needs to bubble up. On top of that if max retries is met, then if I see a 429 I know that I exceeded.